# android screen orientation mixing up

Tags: android, screen-orientation

My android application is designed to be landscape-only. I have put

```
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

into the manifest.
And it really launches in landscape orientation. And that's cool.
But!
I need to know device screen size to perform some calculations. And I have added following code into `onCreate()`:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    // utilize size to calculate something...
```

If I launch the app from portrait orientation, I get (Google Nexus) size.x = 800, size.y = 1205 instead of correct (for landscape) size.x = 1280, size.y = 736.

It seems for me that Android needs some time to switch from portrait to landscape (because eventually I see my app "landscaped"). But `onCreate` is called before this switch -- and it slays my calculations. Is my guess correct?

I tried to move calculations from `onCreate()` to `onGlobalLayout()` but I still get portrait sizes after following steps:

1. launch app in landscape
2. press sleep button (screen goes dark)
3. rotate to portrait orientation
4. press sleep button (screen fades in presenting unlock screen)
5. unlock the device
6. my app wakes up receiving portrait orientation size
7. on next onGlobalLayout() I get landscape size at last, but it's too late.

Can I get rid of portrait orientation completely?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. On my Nexus 4 the activity is locked to landscape and getSize() returns 1196x768, that is 1280 minus size of the navigation bar. Did you do anything else unusual, call  [Activity#setRequestedOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) maybe?

Comment: Also I do not see a switch from portrait to landscape. This should not happen when you specify the orientation in the manifest.

Comment: @devconsole It can be reproduced like this: 1. make device sleeping 2. hold it "portraited" 3. launch your app from eclipse -> unlock screen appears 4. unlock your device 5. observe that size.x < size.y

Comment: Okay, I was able to reproduce it, apparently the unlock screen is locked to portrait and that takes precedence over the setting of the app. BUT as soon as I unlock the screen onCreate() gets called again and it reports the correct dimensions. So isn't this kind of academic? I mean a user won't be able to launch the app while the device is locked under normal circumstances.

Comment: @devconsole At first, thanks for your efforts. I do not want to recreate the layout when screen orientation changes. That's why I added `android:configChanges` (see in question). And under these circumstances I do not get second `onCreate` with "correct" dimensions. As for "academic" -- guess what would happen if user starts my app directly from GooglePlay in portrait orienatation? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent days on this same problem. As other posters revealed, when returning from sleep/lock screen, the app is handed the same portrait mode that the lock screen has. The real find was that it goes through onResume() and onWindowFocusChanged twice - once for the portrait mode, then for the landscape mode. I used the following code in both onResume() and onWindowFocusChanged() to check before executing screen initializations:

```
int gW = view.getMeasuredWidth();
int gH = view.getMeasuredHeight();
if (gW > gH) {// landscape!
// the height will be set at this point
    // so reinitialize your screen here
}
```

It helped me. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot.

If you want to get view sizes you can override the onLayout
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)