# Root layout has portrait dimensions after screen off/on although orientation is landscape

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
    >
    ...
</activity>
```

From the `MainActivity` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Root layout:
    layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    // ...
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.i(TAG, "onResume()");
    Log.i(TAG, "getRequestedOrientation() "+getRequestedOrientation());
    Log.i(TAG, "layout size "+layout.getWidth()+" x "+layout.getHeight());

    // ...
}
```

1) When pausing and resuming the app, this is the expected result - width is > height:

```
I/....MainActivity: onResume()
I/....MainActivity: getRequestedOrientation() 0
I/....MainActivity: layout size 1794 x 1080
```

2) But there is an exception: Only when I have switched the screen off and on again (which pauses and resumes the activity, too), I still get the expected landscape mode as requested orientation, but the dimensions of the layout are as if the activity was in portrait mode:

```
I/....MainActivity: onResume()
I/....MainActivity: getRequestedOrientation() 0
I/....MainActivity: layout size 1080 x 1794
```

3) Since I manage config changes for myself, I see that `Configuration.orientation` switches to portrait after I have switched off the screen; but `onConfigurationChanged(...)` with orientation landscape is only called after `onResume()`, when I turn the screen on again. Anyway, after orientation has changed back to landscape, the sizes are still wrong, but they are right after a certain delay.

4) When logging layout dimensions on demand, I get correct dimensions again.

It's important to note that MainActivity is never destroyed and recreated, which is correct because I have declared the config changes in the manifest. And the activity is in fact still in landscape mode. Probably there is a certain time or an other event that I have to await to **always** get expected dimensions.

The following post has not answered my question: [android screen orientation mixing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775871/android-screen-orientation-mixing-up) - `onResume()` or `onWindowFocusChanged(...)` is never called several times, because the activity persists.